# How to change the apacite/abbrvnat bibliography style to look like regular APA 6/7th [display et al. for 3+ authors and Lastname, F. (year)]?

Tags: natbib, apa-style, apacite, bibliographystyle, abbrvnat.bst

I need to cite and reference using a strict APA 6/7 style. I'm keen on using `natbib` pakage since it provides me with `\citet` and `\citep` commands.
I've managed to achieve accurate in-text citations but my bibliography isn't as it should be. I cannot seem to find a neat way of proper APA referencing with `natbib` package.

I have found a partial solution by modifying a `abbrvnat` bibliography style to display last names first and et al. where 3+ authors. However, this style does not display (year) after the listed authors as required by APA. So, if there's a mean of modifying that within the `abbrvnat.bst` that could my solution.

I also tried using `apacite`, which is preferable as it automatically uses '&' instead of 'and', but it does not display 'et al.' when many authors are listed (it lists many and puts ..., see image). So, being able to somehow modify that to use et al. within references that could be great too.

[image]

To make it clearer I would like my output to be something like this:
[image]

Here is my `main.tex` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, setspace, multirow, lineno, wrapfig, csvsimple,comment,subfigure,makecell,boldline,amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{float} % to insert images where you declare them
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}
\NewDocumentCommand{\codeword}{v}{%
\texttt{\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,labelformat=simple,labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=period}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{rm}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry} %allows for suppressing bibliography 
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-maxbibnames4} %in combo with \usepackage{natbib}

\input{titlepage}
\onehalfspacing

\newpage
\input{Abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\input{Intoduction}

\newpage
\input{Methodology}

\newpage
\input{Results}

\newpage
\input{Discussion}

\newpage

\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If strict adherence to the APA6 guidelines -- while still being able to use `\citet` and `\citep` -- is your goal, you should indeed run `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`.

Comment: You wrote, "I would like my output to be something like this...". Well, that is definitely not allowed under either APA6 or APA7.

Comment: If you need strict APA6, then you can choose between `apacite` or `biblatex-apa6`. If you need strict APA7, then the only LaTeX solution currently available is `biblatex-apa`. `abbrvnat` and friends are unlikely to help us here and modifying it to come close to real APA style is going to be a nightmare. If your only worry is being able to use `\citet` and `\citep` (instead of `apacite`'s slightly less well-known `\cite`, `\citeA`, `\citeNP`), then `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` is the only thing you should need.

Comment: As for the "et al.": It is APA style not to use "et al." in the bibliography. If the name lists are too long, names are omitted, but those are marked with an ellipsis (APA7: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#author, can't find a good official link for APA6 at the moment, but it's the same there with a different limit).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It appears I got misleading information on how APA should look. 
I managed to get to what I needed using `\usepackage{apacite}` and for in-text citations `\shortcite` and `\shortciteA`, which are equivalent to `\citep` and `\citet` in `natbib`. I tried `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` but not everything worked so smooth.